# % signs in a Twitter post using Tweetsharp causes 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

I have a simple piece of code that sends out a Tweet. Keeping the message with the % signs in it causes a 401 Unauthorized error:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new TwitterService("ConsumerKey", "ConsumerSecret", "Token", "TokenSecret");

        try
        {
            // "Test 1, So, I know there's no #inflation and so on...but the 10y inflation swap just went to 2.80%. 5y CPI 5y forward is 3.15%. Hmmm."
            test.SendTweet(WebUtility.HtmlEncode("Test 3, So, I know there's no #inflation and so on...but the 10y inflation swap just went to 2.80%. 5y CPI 5y forward is 3.15. Hmmm."));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Equals(""))
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I send the same message through TweetDeck or directly using the Twitter page, it posts with no problems. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to HTML encode the information before sending it.

Comment: Tried WebUtility.HtmlEncode, no change..

Comment: @Rob - Update your code to reflect your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use a `&#37;` instead of the regular % sign.